# Find the woman/man of your dreams!

Tags: cipher, visual, story

You're on a business trip when you meet Li Xiang, the woman/man of your dreams in the hotel bar. The two of you spend an amazing night together chatting about puzzles, trigonometry, and polyrhythms. (You both love the rhythmic pattern 3 against 5.)  But when you wake up the next morning, Li is gone without a trace!

Dejected, you begin to pack your bags...but what's this? Inside your suitcase, you find a mysterious note scribbled on hotel paper (with immaculate handwriting):

[image]

What is Li's message?

Hint 1:

> [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dsin(n),+y%3Dcos(n),+n%3D0+to+2pi) can be quite helpful for this problem.

Hint 2:

> the x and y formulae each include exactly two trigonometric functions: sine and cosine.

Hint 3:

> Sine and cosine are nested.

Hint 4:

> The following operations are used exactly once in each formula: `sin, cos, +, *`

Hint 5:

> Being a rhythm, 3 and 5 correspond to frequency, not amplitude.

Hint 6:

> `y=cos(n+sin(3n)), x=sin(n+cos(5n))`

Comment: It's worth noting that `n = 0 to 2π` is a full circle in radians.

Comment: [Polyrhythm - 3 against 5 & 5 against 3](https://youtu.be/i-pOP-MdM1M)

Comment: A note for future puzzles - this puzzle basically comes down to "guess the function I used here" which from the information provided in the original puzzle would be a needle-in-a-haystack search.  Puzzles should incorporate clues to how they should be solved - as part of the puzzle itself, not grafted on in spoiler-tagged "hints". If the hint is effectively required for anyone not inside your head to solve the puzzle then it's not a "hint", it's an essential part of the puzzle--and in many cases is the only thing preventing your puzzle from being "guess what I was thinking".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is:

> Meet me at [taoyuan airport](http://www.taoyuan-airport.com/english).

<sub>She/He has probably left by now though :P</sub>

It is obtained by:

> Superimposing the graph of [$y=cos(n+sin(3n)), x=sin(n+cos(5n)), n=0to2\pi$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dcos(n%2Bsin(3n)),+x%3Dsin(n%2Bcos(5n)),+n%3D0+to+2pi) onto the image with the letters and start from the black square beside `m` in clockwise direction.
>  [image: graph on image]

Comment: Aw darn, I had something like that, but I dismissed "taoyua" as gibberish...

Comment: @Lolgast I feel ashamed reaping up your glory! Sorry about that. I was about to give up myself, but I said why don't I google this at least before leaving it. As I started typing `taoy`, google autocomplete it (all of it, even the airport part) and I was like **booyah!!**. That's why I included the link, so people won't think it's just gibberish. After all, it makes perfect sense giving the name in the question is **Li Xiang**. :D

Comment: Ah well, it happens... At least I can live with the knowledge that I found the method and the first part of the message :)

Comment: @Lolgast Yeah, sure! **©opyright Lolgast, all rights reserved**.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> From the hints and the "rhytmic pattern 3 against 5", I got the idea that we might have a formula in the form of
> $x = 3*sin(n)+5*cos(n)$
> $y = 3*cos(n)+5*sin(n)$
> i.e. an ellipse. I tried then overlaying it on the letters, both with the square near m on the origin as on $(3,5)$ (n=0) and with different sizes, hoping to see the ellipse move through different letters which would give a sensible answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't get anything out of it. Perhaps the formulae/shape is a bit more complex, or maybe I just didn't try hard enough.

Revised answer:

> [image]

Still doesn't quite fit, but at least we can see

> Meet me at

Before it turns into gibberish. I've tried different sizes for the overlay, but I couldn't do any better.

Comment: You're on the right track. I'll add another hint.

Comment: Yeah, last night I figured it wouldn't be as simple as this... Would you mind telling me if I'm correct in thinking that the 3 and 5 give the periods in the formulae, rather than the amplitudes as I have now? And whether they're used in both formulae, or 3 for x in 5 for y? (On a side note, because of the flavor text I've looked up heart curves as well on wolfram alpha, but they don't seem to fit the hints...)

Comment: I added two more hints that partially answer your questions!